# Limiting value in text box in Angular for bot max

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I am working in Angular 7. I  want to add min and max property to the textbox but I am facing problem in doing so

```html
  <div>
     <input type='text' [(ngModel)]="toPay" max="20000" min="{{balanceData['res'].toPay}}"   style='width:50%' >
    <p> Please do not pay more then 20,000 and less then required money</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried  without flower braces  min="balanceData['res'].toPay"?

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

try to change type="number" from type="text"

because for type "text" it doesn't have a min and max attributes

Answer (score 0):

It's better to handle this type of code through function not by typical min max function as you are handle the whole numeric data validation.

Whether min max is the length that's typically handle for value length. ex: your min value said 10 So it's length must be 10 or greater than that.

So the code will be as follows:

> HTML part

```
<div>
  <input type='text' [(ngModel)]="toPay" (change)="onValChange()" style='width:50%' >
<p style="color: red" *ngIf="error"> Please do not pay more then 20,000 and less then {{balanceData['res']?.toPay}} in money</p>
</div>
```

> Component Part

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  balanceData: any = {};
  toPay = '';
  error: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.balanceData['res'] = {};
    this.balanceData['res'].toPay = 100;
    // this.toPay = '';
  }
  onValChange() {
    // console.log('Call');
    if (+this.toPay < this.balanceData.res.toPay || +this.toPay >20000){
      this.error = true;
    } else {
      this.error = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I think this way it can be better to handle the error, else you can make a directive to reuse it.

[ONLINE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xfw6b5)